# What causes Goalseek to work manually but not work in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large workbook with many sheets and data. For some reason, when I perform a specific Goalseek manually it works as intended but if I try to do the same exact Goalseek in VBA, it'll update the ideal cells as intended but seems to just stop working. And thus I don't get the desired result. (Seems like Goalseek just stops after a certain number of iterations, possibly after one.)

Any ideas as to what could cause Goalseek to not work in VBA, as opposed to working if ran manually? Also worth noting, I never get a run-time error. The code will execute to the finish, just not with the desired result.

I've tried running the code in a tiny workbook (with 1 sheet of data) and it works as intended, so it's not my syntax that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could try, bearing in mind that I had a similar issue on a large sheet.

In the `Workbook_Open` code block for the workbook you are using - you can add

```
With Application
    .MaxIterations = 500
    .MaxChange = 0.000001
End With
```

Or similar. This will set the maximum amount of iterations and the minimum step changes.

It does sound like its struggling with the amount of calculations involved however, so it may not be the solution.

Comment: This didn't seem to do the trick for me. The runtime was noticeably longer but the result was still way off (trying to set the cell to 0 but it keeps returning -25k). Thanks for the suggestion.